# 'A something shared is an something doubled'?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an English phrase that expresses the idea that sharing something (a meal, a drink, a piece of cake) increases your own enjoyment of it?

Comment: I doubt there would be a common phrase based on the *a [something] shared is a ... **doubled*** format, since that would clash with the well-known [*A **problem** shared is a problem **halved***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+problem+shared+is+a+problem%22).

Comment: A proverb of Swedish origin says "Shared joy is a double joy; shared sorrow is half a sorrow.".

Comment: If you translate your saying it would be "Something shared is something doubled".  "an" + consonant is ungrammatical, and  the indefinite article + something unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

'A meal shared is a meal' gets ~490 Google hits, mostly with "enjoyed" as the last word, but the 3rd one says "A meal shared is a meal doubly savoured".
I wouldn't suggest it was a particularly well-used idiom though.
I also tried 'a moment shared is a moment' and got some interesting results, including "a moment shared is a moment multiplied", that may be a translation from a Danish idiom. There's a book "A life shared is a life lived", but it's hard to determine whether the phrase has much currency outside that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no common English phrase to describe this idea that I've ever heard.  Not a very commonly expressed idea in America (too individualistic perhaps).  Though when I've read it, it wasn't summarized with a neat phrase.  This may be the beginning of another instance of English borrowing a good word or phrase from another language.  Good on the Swedes, I think I'll be using that one.